# On One-Parameter Families of Curves drawn on a 2D lattice Background

Tags: nt.number-theory, discrete-geometry

**Background:** Consider a one parameter family of curves $C(t)$ (where $t$ is the parameter) that together fill the Euclidean plane. As the parameter changes continuously, each member curve is traced. Let us consider only families of curves such that $C(t_1)$ and $C(t_2)$ have at most one intersection if $t_1$ != $t_2$ - for example lines passing thru the same point. For most values of $t$, $C(t)$ will not pass thru any of the lattice vertices (points whose coordinates are both integers). As $t$ changes, $C(t)$ changes and for some special values of $t$, there can be **'events'** when some of the lattice points lie on $C(t)$. As the entire evolution of $t$ is traced, the numbers of events will form a discrete sequence of integers.

**Examples:** If we consider the totality of lines passing thru a point $(a,b)$ where both $a$ and $b$ are irrational, the numbers of events happening simultaneously form the sequence {1, 1, 1, ....} - because  for any value of $t$ (here the angle made by the rotating line), there can at most be one event or none at all. On the other hand, if $a,b$ are both rational, the sequence yielded by the events will be (infinity, infinity, ....) where the 'infinity' is countable. Circles centered at the same point are also a one parameter family of curves.

**Questions:** Are there one parameter families of curves generating events whose numbers are in some *arithmetic progression*? Or can we even assert that **any** arithmetic progression of integers occurs as the numbers of events given by **some** one-parameter family of curves?

And what are the implications of relaxing the at most one intersection between curves corresponding to different $t$ values?